# Sign Ethereum transactions offline using Node-RED

Tags: ethereum, node-red, web3js

I am trying to create a flow in Node-RED to sign for Etherem transactions (in this primary case, just messages) off-line and am struggling.

I have a Python code working fine (meaning doing well this off-line signing) and posting via an API but the Node-RED is not happy doing what I want (it returns a different signature than the one I get on the Web3.py and thus the EVM reverts the transaction).

Can anyone help? I tried several approaches, including the ones commented out, but none will match the signature generated at the Python code...

PS - the Python code implements it with `signed_hash = self.web3.eth.account.signHash(hash, self._fetch_signer_key())`

Thanks!

```
var Web3 = global.get('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

var account = "0x9EfEe29e8fDf2cXXXXXXXde5502ABDf3f13ADac9a";
var privateKey = "0xbde16f62dadb43dad898e182e4e798baXXXXae46458d4939361d2494e11ce9e4";
var password = "12XXX8";

var message = "SMX1 10 1527596375";
var _hash = web3.utils.sha3(message);

//var signedObject = web3.eth.accounts.sign(_hash, privateKey);
var signedObject = web3.eth.accounts.sign(message, account);
//var signedObject = web3.eth.personal.sign(message, account, password);
//const signature = web3.eth.sign(message,account);

var msg = {};
msg.payload = { 
 //"message": message,
 "message": signedObject.message,
 "hash": _hash,
 //"hash": signedObject.messageHash,
 "signature": web3.utils.toHex(signedObject.signature),
 //"signature": web3.eth.personal.sign(message, account, password),
 "identity": identity,
};

/*
//msg.payload = signedObject.message;
msg.payload.message = signedObject.message;
msg.payload.hash = signedObject.messageHash;
msg.payload.signature = signedObject.signature;
msg.payload.identity = identity;
*/

//return signedObject.messageHash;
//return msg;
return signedObject;
```

Comment: Neither do the hashes match...

Comment: If the hashes don't match, then it doesn't make sense to go any further. First determine why the hashes don't match. (If you need help, provide the code you're using to generate the hash in both cases. I believe the JavaScript code is already there, but we're lacking the code in Python that computes the hash.)

Comment: Hi smarx, thanks for getting in touch! The Python code is as simple as the snippet provided previously. Anyway, there is the complete code...
def sign_message(self, message):
        if not isinstance(message, str):
            raise TypeError('Message must be of type <str>')

        hash = Web3.sha3(text=message)

        signed_hash = self.web3.eth.account.signHash(hash, privateKey)

        return signed_hash

Comment: So basically I am looking for a Web3js equivalent to the Web3.py w3.eth.account.signHash(message_hash, private_key=private_key)

Comment: But you said the hash doesn't match in the first place, so the problem is presumably before `signHash`. Unless I'm missing what you mean?

Comment: @smarx, I found the mistake. It was not an actual mistake really. The offline synchronous Web3js function eth.accounts.sign does a weird encapsulation of the message into an object including "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + message.length + message before signing it... This is annoying, once the Python code when I include this envepoe will return the same hashes and signatures as the Node code. 

Now I ask, how do I sign only the message and not the envelope? eth.personal.sign and eth.sign are asynchonous, so I was trying to avoid using them...

Comment: I'm having a really hard time following this thread, so I'm going to bow out. (It seems like this question has been resolved anyway.)

Comment: Yeah, OK, I tweaked the node_module source code to *not* do the enveloping anymore and it succeed...